# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:- Search field

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to search in learning search field in linkedin (https://www.linkedin.com/learning/me?trk=nav_neptune_learning)

1. Login to linkedin
2. Click on "Learning" link(Top right corner)
3. I am sending tab keys and reaching the "search" field
4. Finally find the "search" field using xpath, and I am sending search keyword (.sendKeys("Python")

Selenium with java:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='search-container']/descendant::input[@type='text']")).sendKeys("Python");
```

Till step 3, it's working, search field is highlighted.

The final step always fails, with below exception

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:

I tried the below xpath:

```
//div[@class='container global-nav__container']//div[@class='search-container']/artdeco-typeahead[@id='ember863']/div/input[@type='text']
//div[@class='search-container']/descendant::input[@type='text']
//div[@class='search-container']/artdeco-typeahead[@id='ember863']/div/input[@type='text']
//div[@class='search-container']/artdeco-typeahead/div/input[@type='text']
```

[image]
Interesting thing is with all the above xpath, I am able to find the element in the broswer, but the same xapth doesn't work in selenium code.

My code -Step 4

```
@Test
    public static void search() throws InterruptedException, AWTException
    {

        Robot robot = new Robot();
        for ( int i=0; i<=5;i++)
        {
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']")).sendKeys("Python");
    }
```

Comment: I tried xpath given by you  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']")).sendKeys("Python");  There is  no error but "Python" text is not displayed in the "search" field. Search field is still empty

Comment: Post your HTML code.

Comment: I have included my code. see my question

Comment: //*[@id='ember870']/input try with this xpath.

Comment: I included key release **robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);**  and tried xpath given by you driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']")).sendKeys("Python"); There is no error but "Python" text is not displayed in the "search" field. Search field is still empty

Comment: Use this XPath --->>> //*[@id='ember870']/input

Comment: I got the problem, When I click "Learning" in home page. https://www.linkedin.com/learning/me?trk=nav_neptune_learning link is opened in new tab. So  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']")).sendKeys("Python");  keeps looking in first tab(home page). Now I am trying to find out how to switch control from Home page to Learning page

Answer (score 1):

`NoSuchElementException` happens generally in 2 scenarios.

1. Webelement locator is wrong. (which doesn't seems to be the situation in your case)
2. Your are trying to find the webelement even before it is loaded on the page.(This seems to be your problem)

You are getting the "NoSuchElementException" because your are entering the text even before the webelement on the page has completely loaded.

I would suggest you wait till the webelement that you are looking for to get loaded first and then use sendkeys. Use can use `WebDriverWait` class

so the refactored code should look somewhat like this.

```
//Initializing the 'wait' with a 30 seconds deplay before it throws a NoSuchElementException
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input[placeholder='Search for skills, subjects or software']"));

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[placeholder='Search for skills, subjects or software']")).sendKeys("Python");
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work for you:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[placeholder='Search for skills, subjects or software']")).sendKeys("Python");
```